# How I can import correctly a xls sheet?

Tags: list-manipulation, import, grid-layouts, excel

I have one excel file with a sheet "OK".

[image]

I need to import the file, i tried:

```
s = Import["sales.xls", {"Sheets", "OK"}]

header1 = s[[1]];

data = s[[3 ;;]];

sDataset = Thread[header -> #] & /@ data // Map[Association]
```

But didn't work because the column headers are in the row 1 and 2 after the column 1. I need:

1.) SALES, GM, %GM and EBITDA pear YEAR per MONTH.

Ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For those like me who seem incapable of learning about `Association` and what it can do for me, here is a brute-force method of rearranging your data:

```
data = Import["sales.xls", {"Sheets", "OK"}];

(* Remove headers *)
data = data[[3 ;;]];

(* Attach year and split into separate rows *)
data = Flatten[Table[{Flatten[{2014, data[[i, 1 ;; 6]]}],
Flatten[{2015, data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 7 ;; 11]]}],
Flatten[{2016, data[[i, 1]], data[[i, 12 ;; 16]]}]},
   {i, Length[data]}], 1]

{{2014, "January", 1., 13., 25., 37., 49.},
 {2015, "January", 61., 73., 85., 97., 109.},
 {2016, "January", 121., 133., 145., 157., 169.},
 {2014, "February", 2., 14., 26., 38., 50.},
 {2015, "February", 62., 74., 86., 98., 110.},
 {2016, "February", 122., 134., 146., 158., 170.},
 {2014, "March", 3., 15., 27., 39., 51.},
 {2015, "March", 63., 75., 87., 99., 111.},
.
.
.
 {2016, "December", 132., 144., 156., 168., 180.}}
```

Comment: Thanks. How I can compare for example, ebitda from 2014, 2015 y 2016?

Comment: That's a new question.

Comment: Given the analysis you want do to, it would be better to map the data to TimeSeries. For example, each dimension EBIT etc -> {date, value} and then create a TimeSeries. Use the form from Jim Baldwins answer and use Part[[All, {1, 2}]] to create the dates and then Transpose that result with the value columns.